# Setting height in content slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, height

I made the following content sliding section:
http://jsfiddle.net/JaMYJ/

As you can see, the height of the content on the right loads fine. However, if you click the arrow to move to section two, the content on the right gets cut off.

I know that I can fix this by increasing the height here:
.contentslider .slider ul li {width: 490px; height: 310px;}

However, I don't want to define the height. I want the height to set itself automatically to fit all the content on the right sidebar. I am not sure how to get this right via the css or javascript. Any thoughts??

Thanks so much!!

Comment: I am trying to figure out how the LI's are all getting their height set to a defined value.  If you could prevent that, you would prevent height being an issue.  You could also set the LI's height depending on the current one being displayed (that way if there is one large one there is not a huge space for the smaller ones).

Comment: Thanks Michael. Not sure what to do.. I think the LI's are getting their height from the following CSS selector:
.contentslider .slider ul li

The problem is when I set the height on that property to auto it doesn't seem to do the trick. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the height to `auto` instead of `310px` for `.contentslider .slider ul li`

```
.contentslider .slider ul li {width: 490px; height: auto;}
```

And comment out or remove the line `li.css({width: li.width(), height: li.height()});` from your jQuery. This line is setting the height for your li which is over-writing the CSS li height.

See http://jsfiddle.net/neo108/EyeBb/5/

Comment: Hey there, thanks so much for your help. For some reason, this seems to work fine in the Fiddle. But when I load this on an actual web page, it doesn't solve it :(. Thoughts?

Comment: You are absolutely brilliant. Such a simple fix. THANKS SO MUCH. You're a life saver.